# Can't build todo_ddc project

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, bazel

I want to try polymerize so I have found and use that [post](https://www.dart-polymer.com/polymerize/polymer/mixin/dart/2.x/2017/05/31/demo/). But I met issues when try command

```
pub run polymerize:polymerize build
```

It works some time and then return bazel's error:

```
2017.35.08 16:35:06.015 polymerize      [INFO]: Running bazel ...
____Loading package: 
ERROR: while parsing ':all': error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'BUILD.test_app.bzl': no such package '@build_files//': No WORKSPACE file found in /private/var/tmp/_bazel_kelegorm/df7a1dbca8a607bc3485e726bb483b2b/external/build_files.
```

How can I solve that problem? Why it happens? Why I can't find any mention about that error? What have I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `bazelify`?

Comment: nope, what's this?

Comment: Seems to be now `pub run dazel init`. Did you run that?

Comment: Just tried, demo project hasn't that package. Are you sure? I have read polymerize doesn't use it.

Comment: It's the `dazel` package. I don't know polymerize. The error message is about bazel though.

Comment: can you give more details about `test_app` project ? Seams like you are not talking about the demo `todo_ddc` project so the could be something wrong on `pubspec.yaml` or in the project.

Comment: Just tried new project to check that bug, which is a same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with newest `bazel` versions. Just upgrade to latest `polymerize` (v. `0.8.6+1`)  and it should work again.

To start from a clean workspace just do a :

```
git clone git@github.com:polymer-dart/todo_ddc.git
cd todo_ddc
pub get
pub run polymerize:polymerize build
```